# A controversial question about supremum,maximum,infimum and minimum

Tags: calculus

Question:

$A=\{r \in\mathbb Q\mid r^2\leq5\}$

I tried to look for the answer, but wherever I come, I come across people arguing over the answers:

- $\sup(A)=\sqrt5$
- $\max(A)=\text{none}$
- $\inf(A)=-\sqrt5$
- $\min(A)=\text{none}$

I personally thought it was the first one since the definitions seem to hold with the first answer. What are your thoughts?

Comment: If you're looking in $\mathbb R$, then all four of the statements in your question are correct. I see nothing "controversial" here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The least upper bound of that set as a subset of $(\Bbb R,\le)$ is $\sqrt5$ and its highest lower bound is $-\sqrt5$.

As a subset of $(\Bbb Q,\le)$, that set has neither least upper bound nor highest lower bound.

The ordered set $(\{x\in\Bbb Q\,:\, x^2\le 5\},\le)$ has neither maximum nor minimum.